# What is the effect of ?v=xxxx redirects in url in regards to SEO-scores

Tags: seo, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a website that uses Woocommerce's Geolocate in order to determine content based on a users location, etc.
Unfortunately this results in a '?v=xxxx' redirect.

Does this affect the SEO-score and if so, how badly does it affect it?
Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: SEO isn't a "score."   Search engine optimization is a collection of practices to rank better in search engines and get more traffic from them.   There isn't even a single encompassing metric with which to measure SEO.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the site is automatically redirecting users to a suitable language/region version of a page after detecting the users location?

Google advices not to use geotargeting redirects:

> Avoid automatic redirection based on the user's perceived language.
> These redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from
> viewing all the versions of your site.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#let-the-user-switch-the-page-language

A pop up when detecting users from another location offering people to switch themselves based on their location would be a better option IMO.

From a user perspective, they should not be forced around.
From a search engine perspective, automatic geotargeting redirections should whitelist (not apply to) search engine bots.